# To query using Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

I have below Sql Query which pulls expired tests.

```
cursor.execute('''select
    auth_user.username,
    auth_user.email,
    tests_test.title,
    tests_seller.company_name,
    tests_test.bid_date
    from  tests_test
    LEFT JOIN tests_seller ON tests_seller.id = tests_test.seller_id
    LEFT JOIN auth_user ON auth_user.id = tests_seller.user_id
    where tests_test.bid_date - CURRENT_DATE < 0
''')
```

The above SQL query works fine as expected. But I want to convert the above query for Django ORM. So, could you help me on how to query using Django ORM. Thanks in advance.

**Below are the import statements for models, I planned to use with Django ORM for above sql query**

django.contrib.auth.models import User

from tests.models import Test, Seller

import datetime

Above import statements were used in the separate python script

### Seller model

```
class Seller(models.Model):

    # fields
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What do the Models look like? Is the `tests_seller` table defined in Django as many_to_many intermediate with [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) or just a regular Model?

Comment: Post Your models. Without that, it is not possible to generate ORM Querry

Comment: @C14L, `tests_seller` table defined in Django as a regular model.

Comment: @C14L, I have updated my question by adding `tests_seller` model.

Comment: @C14L, any solution could you provide for this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would look like:

```
Test.objects.filter(bid_date__lt=CURRENT_DATE).values('user__username', 'user__email', 'title', 'seller__company_name', 'bid_date')
```